# Is there a way to make multiple screens in visual studios?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make something that changes what is on the form to something totally different when I press a button. Is it possible to do something like that in visual studios in a way where I can visually edit each screen and not change it all from code?

Answer (score 0):

Just make multiple `UserControl`s, and display one or the other on your `Form`.